# In WordPress do I create tables for my plugin or do I create custom post types for a Student and Classes Registration system?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, database

I want to use WP 4.x as a framework to build a small Student system.  I do not wish to use an existing plugin.  My needs are unique, and these do not do what I need.

In my design, I have Students and Classes.  I thought these should be two content types, but I am not sure.  I looked at a plugin online that created special tables for student registration and classes with SQL, yet in my reading I see others creating custom post types, no SQL, nothing like traditional database table creation outside of WP built in functions.

I do not wish to use Post 2 Post, if at all possible.  But I want to have one student, many classes.

I have seen,

[Creating a relationship between two post types](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/128622/creating-a-relationship-between-two-post-types)

[TV Show database - Best way for structuring it?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/20125/tv-show-database-best-way-for-structuring-it)

Incomplete answer for me:

[Custom post type Vs. data in own table](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/52798/custom-post-type-vs-data-in-own-table)

I am specifically looking for help with how to structure Students and Classes.  I'm just not sure if WP is the correct tool.

[Should I use custom post types or a custom database tables for plugin development?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47915/should-i-use-custom-post-types-or-a-custom-database-tables-for-plugin-developmen)

But my question is different because of the custom post type vs new tables.  What do I do?  Custom Post Types or unique tables with SQL tying them together in a display?

Comment: Did you see this one »[Should I use custom post types or a custom database tables for plugin development?](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/47915/22534)«? For example, because there are a couple more to be found.

Comment: @ialocin still searching as we write.  edit:  I edited the title.

Comment: You are aware that "still searching as we write." sounds like you haven't done your homework before asking here, right? :)

Comment: Sure, no worries, I'm just trying to help you. Although @kraftner has kind of a point.

Comment: @kraftner yes, but I can't give up after I post.  I keep on searching in case missed something.  Not knowing what to search is hard to know sometimes.

Comment: You could try a student CPT with classes as a custom taxonomy. It really depends on the intent of the system.

Comment: @NathanPowell Student Information System.

Comment: Without seeing how the data relates to each other it is hard to say best options.

Comment: @johnny Do you have an example data set you could show, with any possible relationships between the reusable pieces? Or better yet, a proposal on how the system will display and work? Without a bigger picture of the end goal I doubt you will get much help.